# Does GetFullPathName work with relative paths longer than MAX_PATH?

Tags: winapi

The documentation for [`GetFullPathName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that in order to use paths longer than `MAX_PATH` (260 characters) I need to prepend the file namespace prefix: `\\?\`. However, [the general documentation on file names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that this prefix cannot be used with relative paths and thus a relative path's length is always limited to 260 characters. Does this mean there's no way to use `GetFullPathName()` with a relative path longer than `MAX_PATH`? (If so, then my understanding is that the function does not really support long paths unless the passed path is already a full one.)

Comment: http://arsenmk.blogspot.com.au/2015/12/handling-long-paths-on-windows.html claims that `GetFullPathNameW` supports long paths even without the "\\?\" prefix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed, that's nonsensical.  The native api has no concept of relative paths, it is a pure winapi layer feature.  It could be interpreted as a way to get the function to return the native path name.  But it doesn't, I checked.  Looks like a copy/paste doc bug.

Do keep your eye on the ball, when you need GetFullPathName() then you already lost anyway.  Because GetCurrentDirectory() is already subject to the MAX_PATH limit.  So long path support is already out of the window.

The generic advice is to *never* rely on relative paths, even if you don't care about long path support.  Way too many accidents.  With the only reasonable opt-out if you want to write a simple console mode app that is expected to be driven from the command line.  And then you don't care because the command line interpreter is MAX_PATH encumbered.

Comment: the docs for `SetCurrentDirectory` claim that `SetCurrentDirectoryW` supports long paths if you prefix "\\?\". Is this also a mistake?